# Print Shiny App Components (i.e. Data Table) on Paper using Computer's Printer

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, point-of-sale, inventory-management

I am trying an Inventory App using R's Shiny framework. Is there any way I could print specific components of the Web App onto to a paper using Computer's Printer to obtain inventories or other quotations or even receipts?

I am looking for the functionality where I could press a button on my ShinyApp and the print command goes directly to the printer.

*P.S: I am planning to make this app available online using Shinyapps.io dashboard.*

Thanks

Comment: How about generating a PDF/HTML/Word document that could be printed? http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html

Comment: That is one solution. But it would be better if I could print out the inventory or a receipt just by clicking a button on my App

Comment: ok, if you have several possibilities already considered and evaluated and/or a specific solution in mind, please update your question accordingly,...

Comment: alright @BigDataScientist, my bad !

Comment: ive looked into this time and time again and so far as i can find there is no options currently for a direct print. You will have to save to a file and output the file via the OS or a helper application. you could easily make this transparent to the user in a variety of ways. Im designing a POS that is probably needing prints for the same reasons you do and am using the save file/print as a current workaround

Comment: Hi, in that case, you can do this: open your app in a web browser such as Chrome after which you can easily use the Ctrl+P command to create print from your printer.
If anyone has any better solution, do share with us.
Thanks